# React Native - Platform-Independent Tab Navigation Method

Tags: android, tabs, react-native, react-navigation

I have come to a Tutorial to apply an interesting Tabs Navigation, basically it install and use the `react-native-tabs` npm and allow the React Native Application use a Tab
Component that can be run in Both Android and IOS Platform.

The application of the Tutorial Link is simple, the Tab just simple like a Button to change the `Text` content in the Page itself.

I been searching for method to use this `react-native-tabs` npm to Insert a screen from other Javascript file into the Tab, but there are no method regard to this.

**My Issue:**

Is it this`react-native-tabs` npm have limitation that does not able to Specify another JaveScript File Screen into the Tab?

Can anyone show me how to use `react-native-tabs`
    npm to Specify the Tab to display Specific Screen from other Javascript File? Thank You.

Tutorial Link: https://differential.com/insights/sharing-code-between-android-and-ios-in-react-native/

```
import Tabs from 'react-native-tabs';

class ApplicationTabs extends Component{

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        page: 'first'
      };
    }

  render() {
    const { page } = this.state;
    const tabbarStyles = [styles.tabbar];
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') tabbarStyles.push(styles.androidTabbar);

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Tabs
          selected={page}
          style={tabbarStyles}
          selectedStyle={{color:'red'}} onSelect={el=>this.setState({page:el.props.name})}
        >
            <Text name="first">First</Text>
            <Text name="second">Second</Text>
            <Text name="third">Third</Text>
        </Tabs>

        <Text>CodeSharing App</Text>
        <Text>{page}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }


}
```

Screen Output (The Tab Navigation Only navigate to Change the Text on the Screen)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `react-native-tabs npm` maybe was not something that suit me. Instead, I used `react-navigation npm` and it turned out working fine. The only issue is so far I only able to implement StackNavigation.

**Github:** https://github.com/slnn3r/RecipeRedux.git

**The Project above:**

- is using Redux Architecture
- using PHP mySQL database
- using Stack Navigation